# Driver installation issue: Xerox Phaser 6600

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox, postscript, foomatic

The only drivers I was able to find on the Foomatic database are the ones of a different printer (6360DX). I then extracted the PPD drivers from a win 7 driver but the printer config program is not detecting them.
Eventually I downloaded the Linux compatible drivers from the Xerox webpage (a .sh file) which I installed with:
    `sudo sh <filename>.sh`
however, after accepting a Xerox licence agreement, nothing happened and the system still uses the older drivers.
I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
What can I do to effectively install the correct drivers?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem since the original post?

Comment: I downloaded the "Linux Intel Driver (x64) Debian" driver from here: http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6600/downloads/enca.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en which is an .sh file. I ran the script (as root), but I don't see the Phaser 6600 as an option when choosing the driver in CUPS. I'm also using the 6360 driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, I've successfully printed a Test Page to a Networked Xerox Phaser 6600DN. Here is how:

First, Download the aforementioned "Linux Intel Driver (x64) Debian" from Xerox's Driver Download Page; but after that, Change "Operating System" to ANY Windows version between "XP" and "10" (32 or 64 Bits), and get the installer for "Windows XXX PostScript PPD Driver Files". Inside that little ".exe" file, there are 4 PPD Files. You want to extract "xr6600dn.ppd", and copy it to "/opt/Xerox/prtsys" (to keep it available System Wide).

You can easily  extract the appropriate PPD File from the EXE with "7z", found in the "p7zip-full" Package (although, I extracted it with "7-Zip File Manager", which runs perfectly well through WINE).

After installing the Linux Driver, run `sudo xeroxprtmgr` in order to configure the Printer Queue. For this, click on the top leftmost square button in the Interface that will open, to perform a "Discover". Then, click on your Printer in the List (IMPORTANT!) to "Select it", then click on the left button to "Add Printer".

Now, click on your Printer in the List, then click the top right button, then "Queue Preferences". Now, I suggest you jump right to "Configuration" (rightmost tab), and click on "Bidirectional Configuration"; then click "Yes", and enter your Printer's IP Number in the text field, then click OK. By doing that, you'll have real time Printer Status monitoring, plus all your Printer's Setting will be "imported". Now you can configure all your Printer's Parameters the you like.

Now, go to "System Settings" --> "Printers", and REMOVE any Printer Queue the Xerox Utility might have added by itself.

Now, add your Printer. It should be automatically discovered in 2 or more "flavors", from which I chose the "AppSocket/JetDirect network printer via DNS-SD" one (I assume all your Printer's Protocols are "ON"). Then, "Manually Provide a PPD File" you just stored at "/opt/Xerox/prtsys/xr6600dn.ppd", configure a Queue Name.

Apart from the Printer's Name and Description, there is not much you can configure here. Just DON'T TOUCH the "Connection" String, and go print a Test Page.

Comment: Anyway, the only thing really important about the "Linux Driver" from Xerox, is the Printer's Configuration Program, The REAL Driver here, is the PPD File.